# Catgories didn't work

Tags: php, mysql

So I try to learn php and decided to make one site where I add images, save them in folder and id, name,type, path in mysql. Then show on page. So far I have upload form and I can upload and save images. Also I showing them successfully on the page.

Now I'm trying to make categories like - Nature, Funny ... etc. So I added one field in my main table -> img_category.
Also I madded second table - cats whit cat_id and cat_name fields. Using this to show the categories on the page:

```
         <?php
        $q = mysqli_query($con,"select * from cats");
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='. $res['cat_id'] .'">'.$res['cat_name'].'<br/>';
        }
```

So now how can I make when I click on some category link to load images only from this category?
I have managed to make something like this but it doesn't work like is expected

```
<?php
        $q = mysqli_query($con,"select * from cats");
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='. $res['cat_id'] .'">'.$res['cat_name'].'<br/>';
        }

        ?>
        <hr>
        <?php
        $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM images JOIN cats ON images.img_category = cats.cat_id WHERE cats.cat_id = '$cat_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));

        $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
        if (!$line) echo '';
        $previd = -1;
        $currid = $line[0];
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            do {
                $currid = $line[0];
                if ($currid == $_GET['id']) break;
                $previd = $currid;
                $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
            } while ($line);
        }

        if ($line) {
            echo "<div id=\"picture\">";

            echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$line['name']."\" /></a><br />";
            echo "<div id=\"caption\">".$line['caption']."</div><br />";
        }
        else echo "There is no images!\n";

        if ($previd > -1) echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$previd.'" class="prev_pic"><span>Prev</span></a>';
        echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);

        $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);

        $query = "select * from images order by RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
            echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$row['id'].'"class="random">Random</a>';
        }
        echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
        if ($line) echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$line[0].'" class="next_pic"><span>Next</span> </a><br /><br />';

        echo "</div>";

        ?>
```

The results are:

When there is image in the category is showed but and if I click on 'Next' button I get the same image.
If there is no image in the category I get all echoes like link whit the ID of last category for exam: There is no image like link and if I click it I get last category ID loaded. In my case I have 8 categories so ID=8.
Any help is appreciate!
Thank's

EDIT:
Ok this line:

```
echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$line[0].'" class="next_pic"><span>Следваща</span> </a>
```

Where is pic.php?cat_id=... i think is wrong. Here I must take next image ID not next category ID. But how to change it for image? If i make it pic.php?id=... I get empty page.
I don't understand it. I know that is messy code but is best I can do for now.

EDIT 2:
I've made something like this. Now can you help me how to make query's for next image because now didn't get next image and stay the same.

```
$cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
        $cat_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $cat_id);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM images JOIN cats ON images.img_category = cats.cat_id WHERE cats.cat_id = '$cat_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));
$prevSQL = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cat_id FROM cats WHERE cat_id < $cat_id ORDER BY cat_id DESC LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($con));
        $nextSQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT cat_id FROM cats WHERE cat_id > $cat_id ORDER BY cat_id ASC LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($con));
        $prevobj=mysqli_fetch_object($prevSQL);
        $nextobj=mysqli_fetch_object($nextSQL);
        $pc = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(cat_id) as pid FROM cats WHERE cat_id<$cat_id ORDER BY cat_id DESC")) or die (mysqli_error($con));
        $nc = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(cat_id) as nid FROM cats WHERE cat_id>$cat_id ORDER BY cat_id ASC")) or die (mysqli_error($con));
        $prev=$pc->pid>0 ? '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&id='.$prevobj->cat_id.'">Prev</a> |' : '';
        $next=$nc->nid>0 ? '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&id='.$nextobj->cat_id.'">Next</a>' : '';
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo "<div id=\"picture\">";
        echo "<img src=\"upload/" . $row['name']  . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
        echo $row['caption'] . "<br />";
        echo "</p>";
        echo $prev;
        echo $next;
```

Comment: SQL Injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I don't know yet how to make this..

Comment: Yes you do. You already created some nice injection point in your code.

Comment: Yes, I mean I don't know yet how to secure this :)

Comment: There is a chapter dedicated to mitigation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Mitigation . Try escaping your input variables. Also never trust any variable provided by an external source (user, url, etc)

Comment: You mean something like `$cat_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $cat_id);` right after sql query?

Comment: No! Before the query, the injection happens in the sql query.

Comment: Yes my bad.. Must be before.. there is no point to be after. Since I use only $cat_id variable in query I need only this to secure?

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, I guess the error is with the line:

```
echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$line[0].'" class="next_pic"><span>Следваща</span> </a>
```

I think it should be:

```
echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$line[0].'&id='.$next_picture_id.'" class="next_pic"><span>Следваща</span> </a>
```

**EDIT:**
Your code should look like:

```
<?php
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"select * from cats");
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='. $res['cat_id'] .'">'.$res['cat_name'].'<br/>';
    }

    ?>
    <hr>
    <?php
    $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images JOIN cats ON images.img_category = cats.cat_id WHERE cats.cat_id = '$cat_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));

    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
    if (!$line) echo '';
    $previd = -1;
    $currid = $line[0];
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        do {
            $currid = $line[0];
            if ($currid == $_GET['id']) break;
            $previd = $currid;
            $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
        } while ($line);
    }

    if ($line) {
        echo "<div id=\"picture\">";

        echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$line['name']."\" /></a><br />";
        echo "<div id=\"caption\">".$line['caption']."</div><br />";
    }
    else echo "There is no images!\n";

    if ($previd > -1) echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$previd.'" class="prev_pic"><span>Prev</span></a>';
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);

    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);

    $query = "select * from images order by RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$row['id'].'"class="random">Random</a>';
    }
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
    if ($line) echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$line[0].'&id='.$line[0].'" class="next_pic"><span>Next</span> </a><br /><br />';

    echo "</div>";

    ?>
```

Comment: I get `Undefined variable: next_picture_id`

Comment: I see... it happens where there's no id... I'm going to edit the resonse

Comment: try now... I replaced the next_pic link

Comment: Now is a bit better but still has something wrong. When I open the category for example "Animals" where I have 3 images ID's 1,2,3 when I'm on 2 and hit 'Next' for 3 i get 'There is no image'.

Comment: On category "Auto" I have 2 images and after first when i try to open second one I get again this "There is no image" What can be wrong now?

Comment: When you're on 'Animals' second image, what is the `next` link href value?

Comment: On second image is `pic.php?cat_id=2&id=2` when I click for 3rd image link is `pic.php?cat_id=3&id=3` but 'There is no image'. Getting next category instead of same category but next image.

Comment: And there's an image with id=3 ?

Comment: Yes, there is..The problem is why getting next image from next category instead next image from the current category?

Comment: I think the problem is that when you're building prev a next links, you'retaking the category id for the url parameter 'id'... For this parameter you should use the picture id.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is how? How to stay on same category and take just next image id? Any idea?

Comment: Simple: you must build the link's URL with 2 parameters: category_id and image_id, something like: `pic.php=cat_id=2&id=3` . Then, in your script, get those parameters from the `REQUEST` and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
            $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE img_category = '$cat_id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));

            $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
            if (!$line) echo '';
            $previd = -1;
            $currid = $line[0];
            if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                $previous_ids = array();
                do {
                    $previous_ids[] = $line[0];
                    $currid = $line[0];
                    if ($currid == $_GET['id']) break;
                    $previd = end($previous_ids);
                    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
                } while ($line);
            }

            if ($line) {
                echo "<div id=\"picture\">";

                echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$line['name']."\" /><br />\r";
                echo "<div id=\"caption\">".$line['caption']."</div><br />";
            }
            else echo "There is no images!\n";

            if ($previd > -1)
                echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&amp;id='.$previd.'" class="prev_pic"><span>Prev</span></a>';
            echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);

            $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);

            $query = "select * from images WHERE img_category = '$cat_id' order by RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
                echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&amp;id='.$row['id'].'"class="random">Random</a>';
            }
            echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
            if ($line) echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&amp;id='.$line[0].'" class="next_pic"><span>Next</span> </a><br /><br />';

            echo "</div>\r";
        }
        ?>
```